# javascript push one multidimensional array into another multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, multidimensional-array, push

I have two multidimensional arrays that I would like to be one multidimensional.
I have tried to use push but I'm sure I missing something, because Array1 only get a undefined into it.
Anyone there can help?

```
var Array1 = Array( { Felt: "#Field1", Validering: "min", Krav: 2, SpanID: "#span1" },
                { Felt: "#Field2", Validering: "min", Krav: 2, SpanID: "#span2" },
                { Felt: "#Field3", Validering: "lig", Krav: 10, SpanID: "#span3" },
                { Felt: "#Field4", Validering: "min", Krav: 6, SpanID: "#span4" },
                { Felt: "#Field5", Validering: "min", Krav: 6, SpanID: "#span5" },
                { Felt: "#Field6", Validering: "min", Krav: 1, SpanID: "#span6" });

var Array2 = Array( { Felt: "#Field7", Validering: "min", Krav: 2, SpanID: "#span7" },
                    { Felt: "#Field8", Validering: "min", Krav: 2, SpanID: "#span8" },
                    { Felt: "#Field9", Validering: "lig", Krav: 10, SpanID: "#span9" },
                    { Felt: "#Field10", Validering: "lig", Krav: 10, SpanID: "#span10" },
                    { Felt: "#Field11", Validering: "lig", Krav: 11, SpanID: "#span11" });
```

UPDATE: 
I used this solution:

```
Array1 = Array1.conat(Array2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to join arrays? Use `Array.concat()` method

```
Array.concat(Array1, Array2);
console.log(Array1);
```

Comment: Maybe a stupit question, but how can I close this thread, and let you get the credits??